# Is the following set a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a set of vectors $S$ which are of the form:
$$S = \{ \left(\begin{matrix}
a,&b,&c
\end{matrix}\right)
\mid a, b,c  \in \Bbb R  \}.
$$

The set is simply what is shown above. Nothing else. I feel like it should be simple to show but I think I'm missing something.

So if I had the given vectors $x$ and $y$ = $$x = { \left(\begin{matrix}
a_1,&b_1,&c_1
\end{matrix}\right) }  
$$
$$y = { \left(\begin{matrix}
a_2,&b_2,&c_2
\end{matrix}\right) }  
$$

How would I show that they are still closed in $\Bbb R^3$ for addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: You can type `\{` and `\}` to get the curly braces.

Comment: It looks like your set has exactly one element. Such a set _may_ be a subspace, but whether it in fact is, depends on what $a$, $b$, and $c$ are.

Comment: a,b,c can be any real numbers. Sorry I should have specified.

Comment: Then your set either is or is not a subspace; you do not have enough information to tell. $S$ is a subspace if $a=b=c=0$, and is not a subspace otherwise.

Comment: How do I know that there is not enough information to tell? I would have thought since a1 + a2, b1 + b2 etc. all produce real numbers that it would still be within R^3. Similarly for scalar multiplication they would all still produce real numbers.

Comment: The case where a = b = c = 0 would still surely be within this set though. Which means that because of what I also wrote above it is still a subspace?

Comment: You have edited the question. Before the edit, you specified that $S$ is a set with exactly one element. Such a set is a subspace if and only if that single element is the zero vector After the edit, you're defining $S$ to be the same set as $\mathbb R^3$  itself; that is obviously a subspace.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But that is what I had originally wanted to write. I can see that it is obviously a subspace. But how do I put that into writing?

Comment: That depends on which definitions and concepts you have available to you. I would just write "a vector space is always a subspace of itself", and prove that as a lemma if necessary. However, if you haven't learned about abstract vector spaces in general, and are only dealing with $\mathbb R^n$ and its subspaces yet, that would not make sense in your context.

Comment: You simply need to check that for x, y in S, $x+ky$ is also in S (has the same form or meets the condition to be in S)